# Compass using expo to record values of magnetometer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to make an app that makes a compass and compass should changes with changing direction of magnetometer. The code attached below shows a strange error. Although I have run `npm install react-timer-mixin` to sort the problem.By running this code on Expo it shows an error like

> Super expression must either be a null or a function.

```
import React, {Components} from 'react';
import {Image, ImageBackground, View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Expo from 'expo';

export default class App extends Components{
  state={
    isReady: false,
    v: null,
  };

  _setMagnetometerAsync = async() =>{
    Expo.Magnetometer.addListener((v)=>{
      this.setState({v});
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this._setupMagnetometerAsync();
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.v)}</Text>
      <ImageBackground
      source = {require('./compassFace.png')}
      style = {{
        height: 320,
        width: 320,
        paddingTop:Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContents: 'center',
      }}>
        <Image
        source = {require('./CompassNeedle.png')}
        style={{
          height: 420,
          width: 420,
          opacity: 0.65,
        }}
        />
      </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  paragraph:{
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#34495e',
  },
});
```

[image: The development server returned response error 500]

Comment: Do you use react-native-easy-grid in your project?

Comment: yes...it shows an error like this "Super expression must either be null or a function"

Comment: Can you post your in expo snack?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@atiariaz/3fa109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some fixes:
1.

```
import React, {Components} from 'react';
```

to

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

2.

```
 componentDidMount(){
        this._setupMagnetometerAsync();
      }
```

to

```
 componentDidMount(){
        this._setMagnetometerAsync();
      }
```

3.

```
 export default class App extends Components{
```

to

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
```